# Angle between two random unit vectors uniformly distributed

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, uniform-distribution, spheres, statistical-mechanics

Consider $x, y \in S_{1}^{d-1}$ (the unit n-sphere in d dimensions) with $(x \cdot y)^2 = 1/d$. I need to compute the angle $\alpha$ between $x$ and $y$ for $d$ = $3$ and asymptotically for large $d$. I have prove that $E[(x \cdot y)^2] =1/d$ but I don´t know how can I compute the angle.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will receive better feedback from the community if you provide some of your work :-).

Comment: The random unit vectors $X$ and $Y$ don't seem to appear anywhere in the problem... Are the $x$ and $y$ that appear later supposed to be the same?

Comment: @MishaLavrov oh yes sorry, I will fix the question

Comment: @TaylorRendon I have tried with the Expected value and I think that for large $d$ the angle will be $\pi / 2$ but I dont´k know how compute the case d=3

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ is large enough, $\mathbb{E}[(x\cdot y)^2]\approx 0$, therefore $\cos^2\alpha\approx0$. By using Taylor expansion at $\alpha=\pi/2$, which is

$$\cos^2\alpha=(\alpha-\pi/2)^2-1/3(\alpha-\pi/2)^4+\cdots$$

We get

$$\mathbb{E}[\cos^2\alpha]\approx\mathbb{E}[(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2})^2]\approx 1/d$$